# Selenide + React: выбор элемента по нужному тексту из выпадающего списка

Tags: java, css, reactjs, selenide

В автотесте необходимо добавить шаг выбора элемента из выпадающего списка: внутреннее /международное

Так как разработчики использовали какую-то библиотеку (к сожалению, не разбираюсь в этом), то обычными известными мне способами выполнить выбор не получается(

Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно осуществить выбор?

мой "не работающий" вариант:
`$(By.xpath("//div[@id='rpoDirectCategorySection-select']//div[@class='css-0 appSelectBulk__single-value']")).setValue("внутреннее");`

Получаю ошибку: `Element not found {By.xpath: //div[@id='rpoDirectCategorySection-select']//div[@class='css-0 appSelectBulk__single-value']} Expected: visible`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: html]

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, xpath неправильный. На первый выглядит корректным, но всё-таки селениум не смог по нему найти элемента.

1. Полный стектрейс (включая всю цепочку "Caused by: ..." может помочь.
2. Я бы посоветовал упростить селектор. Вместо этого xpath лучше использовать более короткий CSS селектор: `$("#rpoDirectCategorySection-select .css-0.appSelectBulk__single-value").setValue("внутреннее");`

Comment: все равно не видит этого элемента: `Element not found {#rpoDirectCategorySection-select.css-0.appSelectBulk__single-value}
Expected: visible`                                                                                                                                  
  `Caused by: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#rpoDirectCategorySection-select.css-0.appSelectBulk__single-value"}
 at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebElementSource.createElementNotFoundError(WebElementSource.java:31)`

Comment: Что я могу сказать - вебдрайвер не смог найти элемент. Значит, всё-таки локатор неверный.

Comment: Удалось решить проблему так:
`$(By.xpath("//div[@id='rpoDirectCategorySection-select']//div[@class='css-151xaom-placeholder appSelectBulk__placeholder']")).click();  

$(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'css-0 appSelectBulk__option') and contains(text(), 'внутреннее')]")).click();`

Comment: теперь другая проблема:  

при запуске в режиме отладки все отрабатывает, но не в режиме отладки элемент почему-то не виден:  
`Element not found {By.xpath: //div[contains(@class, 'css-0 letter-dropdown__option') and contains(text(), mailType)]}
Expected: visible`  
  
`Caused by: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class, 'css-0 letter-dropdown__option') and contains(text(), mailType)]"}
 at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebElementSource.createElementNotFoundError(WebElementSource.java:31)`